# derivative of an improper integral with variables in the limits

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I came across the following integral and its evaluation in a scientific paper on sediment transport (https://doi.org/10.1061/(ASCE)0733-9429(2000)126:11(818) if you're interested) and I verified it in wolfram alpha, but I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand why it's true.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just looks like an application of the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Leibniz integral rule, we should have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{-\infty}^x f(y) \left(\int_{x - y}^\infty g(t) dt\right) dy = \left[f(y)\left(\int_{x - y}^\infty g(t) dt\right)\right]_{y = x} + \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[f(y) \left(\int_{x - y}^\infty g(t) dt\right)\right] dy$$

Evaluating the first term and reusing the Leibniz rule on the second term yields

$$f(y)\int^\infty_0 g(t) dt + \int_{-\infty}^x f(y) (-g(x - y)) dy$$

which matches your right-hand side.